# Alexa pageview tracking for websites with Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alexa-skills-kit

I have a web site that is used infinite scroll like Facebook and Twitter. Whenever the user scrolls down, new contents appear so the usability of the site increases.

Google counts this scroll move and retrieving new content set as pageview (using _gaq.push), however Alexa does not. I couldn't find anything in Javascript API of Alexa.

Alexa provides the following script to track visits :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _atrk_opts = {atrk_acct: "MY_ID", domain: "MY_SITE", dynamic: true};
    (function () {
        var as = document.createElement('script');
        as.type = 'text/javascript';
        as.async = true;
        as.src = "https://ANOTHER_ID.cloudfront.net/atrk.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s);
    })();
</script>
<noscript><img src="https://ANOTHER_ID.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=MY_ID" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" /></noscript>
```

If I put this block to another page that is called as "load more / scroll move" action from a main page, Alexa doesn't count.

In other words, if I put the script to all pages including the loadmore pages it doesn't work. In each scroll down action, a loadmore page is called and putting the source code in a div in main page (the page where the loadmore page is called) For example after the 5 times scroll, the source becomes like the source of the following pages :

```
mainpage.jsp
loadmore.jsp?page=1
loadmore.jsp?page=2
loadmore.jsp?page=3
loadmore.jsp?page=4
loadmore.jsp?page=5
```

In this case, it only counts 1. It means only the javascript block in mainpage.jsp works.

Do you have any solution to make Alexa track scroll-loaded pages as pageview ?